After importing using wordpress importer, posts in duotone theme do not pick up background colours from image
In wordpress.org: After importing using wordpress importer, posts in duotone theme do not pick up background colours from image. The posts in the original website have the correct background.
If I edit a post and the update it without making any changes, that post will then be displayed with the correct background. That could be a workaround but would be tedious for a large number of posts.
Is there any way to force Wordpress to recalculate the backgrounds in a more simple way?

Oops, maybe this was a little too obvious. The following works (at least with WordPress 4.2.3).

Login to .../wordpress/wp-admin;
Go to Posts => All posts;
Click on Screen Options;
Set "Number of items per page:" to a number greater than the number of posts you have;
Click "Apply";
Click on the box at the top left of the list of posts (next to the heading "Title");
On the "Bulk Actions" drop-down menu, select "Edit";
Click "Apply";
You will see a "BULK EDIT" list; do nothing except click on "Update";
After a delay, you will see the All posts page again with the message "xxx posts updated";

Now the backgrounds will be updated.
